# Membership.DeleteUser() fails with RI Constraint

Tags: c#, asp.net-membership

I'm missing a concept here. I was assuming that `Membership.DeleteUser()` would expunge a user from my membership tables. My code:

```
// remove all but 'admin' from Membership
MembershipUserCollection users = Membership.GetAllUsers();

foreach ( MembershipUser user in users )
{
    if ( user.UserName != "admin" )
    {
        Membership.DeleteUser( user.UserName );
    }
}
```

`DeleteUser()` fails with exception:

```
The DELETE statement conflicted with the REFERENCE constraint 
"FK__aspnet_Me__UserI__58D1301D". The conflict occurred in database 
"MyDatabase", table "dbo.aspnet_Membership", column 'UserId'.
The statement has been terminated.
```

In my Web.config:

```
<membership defaultProvider="MyMembershipProvider">
  <providers>
    <clear/>
    <add name="MyMembershipProvider" type="System.Web.Security.SqlMembershipProvider" connectionStringName="MembershipConnectionString" enablePasswordRetrieval="false" enablePasswordReset="true" requiresQuestionAndAnswer="false" requiresUniqueEmail="false" maxInvalidPasswordAttempts="5" minRequiredPasswordLength="5" minRequiredNonalphanumericCharacters="0" passwordAttemptWindow="10" applicationName="MyApplication"/>
  </providers>
</membership>
```

I get it that there's a foreign key relationship between `Membership.UserId -> Users.UserId` but would have assumed that the whole point of `DeleteUser()` is to remove all the records for this user in the `Membership`, `User` and `UsersInRoles` tables, to name a few.

Of course, I could go straight into the `Membership` table and delete the appropriate record, but that's defeating the purpose of using the API. What am I doing wrong? What is the correct way to delete a user from the Membership tables?

Comment: Are you using the default SqlMembershipProvider?

Comment: @MystereMan - yes I am, see edits above.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Well, `Membership.DeleteUser(string)` calls `SqlMembershipProvider.DeleteUser(string, bool)` with true, and that calls the stored proc `aspnet_Users_DeleteUser`.  That sproc has code in it to delete the various extra data in other tables that are related.

You can check your sproc to see if it's been altered.

The only other thing I can think of is whether or not you created any other foreign key relationships to the Membership tables, such as to your own users table?  If so, you would have to delete those records first.  This is one reason it's not recommended to create such foreign key relationships.

Check the FK relationships on the aspnet_Membership table and see if there are any that shouldn't be there.

Comment: To your point, I *wanted* to make such foreign key relationships, but decided that would be a very bad idea. For now, I've found something that works that involves directly deleting records from the Membership and UsersInRoles tables. See my most recent edit, above. I'm not terribly pleased with this, but since this is part of a skunkworks page that's only to be used by the site administrator, which is me for now, I'll let it stand.

Comment: @BobKaufman - if you ever want to solve the problem, you're going to have to look at the sproc and see why it's not deleting the dependent data.

Comment: @BobKaufman - did you by any chance delete the aspnet views?  particularly, vw_aspnet_UsersInRoles?  If that view doesn't exist, it won't delete the objects

Comment: The stored proc looks fine... but there are no views in the database for the Membership API. I'm guessing they got wiped out... and are the source of my problem!

Comment: @BobKaufman - you can find the original view definitions in C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319 in the .sql files (search for *.sql)

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem. For me, it turned out to be because my database had the tables and stored procs for ASP membership but not the views. I installed the nine views, and then it worked. I figured it out by looking at the implementation of the SP aspnet_Users_DeleteUser. In it, you can see that for some weird reason, it looks to see if the views exist before deleting records from some of the tables. Since the view didn't exist in my DB, it wasn't deleting the records from aspnet_Membership first.