# Membership.DeleteUser() do not delete user

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server-2008, asp.net-membership

When I use **Membership.DeleteUser(userName, false)** nothing happens.
But When I use **Membership.DeleteUser(userName, true)** or **Membership.DeleteUser(userName)** error is thrown.

```
The DELETE statement conflicted with the REFERENCE constraint "FK__aspnet_Pr__UserI__3F115E1A".
The conflict occurred in database "MyDB", table "dbo.aspnet_Profile", column 'UserId'.
```

Here is my table key structures:

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Can anybody help me out in solving this issue.?Not getting any idea.

Comment: I think you will find your answer here: <http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12763229/membership-deleteuser-fails-with-ri-constraint>

Comment: I have read that post but according to @Erik There should not be any foreign key on Membership table.When I try to delete it throws error.Could not drop the constraint.'FK_aspnet_Me_Appli_47A6A41B' is not a constraint.

Comment: Have you customised the database in any way?

Comment: I have to alter the table Profile,Users and Membership by adding ON DELETE CASCADE ,then it deletes the user correctly.Why?

Comment: I want to delete data only from Users table not from Profile and Membership table.How can I achieve it without using On DELETE CASCADE

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use ON DELETE CASCADE

it will specify whether you want rows deleted in a child table when corresponding rows are deleted in the parent table. If you do not specify cascading deletes, the default behavior of the database server prevents you from deleting data in a table if other tables reference it.

see http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/idshelp/v10/index.jsp?topic=/com.ibm.sqls.doc/sqls292.htm